# How to show output one screen by another

Tags: ansible

Hi I use command "cat ansible.cfg". Once the command is entered, all the output goes away on the screen. I want to see it one screen by one. What correct command should i use? Thank you

Answer (score 1):

This isn't really an ansible question, as you are really just using the `cat` command to view a text tile that happens to be an ansible config.

See this link for information on how to view files in Unix/Linux: https://www.baeldung.com/linux/files-cat-more-less

In short, however, `less` and `more` are both utilities for viewing files one page at a time like you requested. Just enter `more ansible.cfg` and then use the space bar to advance a page at a time.